# ¿Como abrir una ventana en WPF sin romper el patrón MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, patrones-de-diseño

hace poco tiempo trabajo con WPF, y hoy por primera vez se me presenta la situación de tener que abrir una nueva ventana, si bien es sencilla, se me presentó el problema de no saber como abrirla sin romper el patron MVVM.

Usualmente, haría algo como lo siguiente..

```
public static void OpenWindow<T>(object dataContext)
    where T : IWindow, new()
{
    T t = new (t);
    t.DataContext = dataContext;
    t.Show();
}
```

El asunto, es, que de esta manera, dentro del ViewModel, debería saber el nombre de la vista

```
public class AViewModel
{
    public ICommand AbrirVentana 
    { 
        get 
        {
            //A es el nombre de la vista dentro del ejemplo
            return new RelayCommand((e) => WindowService.OpenWindow<A>(/*my otro ViewModel*/));
        }
    }
}
```

Como puedo abrir una nueva ventana, o dialogo sin romper el patrón MVVM?

Comment: Yo como recomendación rápida te diría que no le des muchas vueltas, MVVM está muy bien pero a veces seguirlo al pie de la letra da mas problemas que hacer alguna pequeña excepción. En tu caso, no veo problema en que pases el viewmodel directamente

Comment: @Pikoh gracias por la recomendación, vos crees que una implementación similar a la del ejemplo sería válida?

Comment: Perfectamente válida, yo hago algo similar en mis aplicaciones. De todas maneras, esperemos otras opiniones y a lo mejor aprendemos algo ambos :)

Comment: Creo que tengo la respuesta pero no estoy claro con la pregunta, lo que quieres es abrir UNA ventana específica con MVVM o abrir varias ventanas o cuadros de diálogo indistintamente usando el mismo ICommand? Lo pregunto porque puedes tener un ICommand para cada ventana o cuadro de diálogo que quieras abrir y lo apuntas a un método que abra una ventana por cada ICommand, pero si quieres usar el mismo para varias ventanas también se puede, en ese caso lo más rápido es enviar el nombre de la ventana por CommandParameter y luego abrirla con un switch, espero tu comentario para responder..

Comment: @Leodev gracias por el comentario, lo que pretendo, es que con cada ICommand abrir otra ventana sin romper el patrón mvvm, por ende, sin mencionar la vista propia dentro del vm

Comment: Muy buenas, en aplicaciones "grandes" se suele utilizar el patrón `event aggregator`. Te dejo este [enlace](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/) que espero te aclare un poco el tema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero que te pueda ayudar, es algo complejo pero util.

Puedes utilizar esto:

```
public class MainVm 
{
        private IPresenter<ClientVm> clientPresenter;
        //Utiliza dentro de un comando
        private void OpenCommandExecute(object obj)
        {
            var vM = new ClientVm();
            this.clientPresenter = new ClientPresenter(vM);
            this.clientPresenter.Closed += this.ClientPresenterClosed;
            this.clientPresenter.OpenModal();
        }

        //
        private async void ClientPresenterClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var p = sender as ClientPresenter;
            if (p != null)
            {
                //Detectar si se guardo. para llamar algun metodo
                if (p.ViewModel.IsSaved)
                {
                   await this.Load();
                }
            }

            this.DisposePresenter();
        }

    private void DisposePresenter()
    {
        try
        {
            if (this.clientPresenter != null)
            {
                this.clientPresenter.Closed -= this.ClientPresenterClosed;
                this.clientPresenter.Dispose();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            this.clientPresenter = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Es necesario crear el presenter:

```
internal class ClientPresenter : Presenter<ClientWindow, ClientVm>
{
    public ClientPresenter(ClientVm viewModel) : base(new ClientWindow(), viewModel)
    {
    }
}
```

ClientWindow necesita heredar de BaseWindow

```
<utils:BaseWindow>
...
</utils:BaseWindow>
```

El ClientVm necesita heredar de BaseEditableViewModel

```
public class ClientVm : BaseEditableViewModel{}
```

Pero primero necesitas implementar:

```
public interface IOpenable
{
    void Open();
    bool? OpenModal();
    void Focus();
}
```

Implementar:

```
public interface IPresenter<T> : IPresenter
    where T : IBaseViewModel
{
    T ViewModel { get; }

    void ReplaceViewModel(T viewModel);
}
```

Implementar:

```
public interface IPresenter : IClosable, IOpenable
{

}
```

Implementar:

```
public class Presenter<TW, TVM> : IPresenter<TVM>
    where TW : BaseWindow where TVM : class, IBaseViewModel
{
    private TVM viewModel;

    public Presenter(TW window, TVM viewModel)
    {
        // Check
        if (window == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("window");
        }
        if (viewModel == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("viewModel");
        }
        //ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(window);

        // Assign
        Window = window;
        Window.Closed += OnWindowClosed;
        ViewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public TW Window { get; set; }

    public TVM ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return this.viewModel;
        }
        private set
        {
            if (this.viewModel != null)
            {
                this.viewModel.Closed -= this.OnViewModelClosed;
                this.viewModel.Dispose();
            }
            this.viewModel = value;
            if (this.viewModel != null)
            {
                this.viewModel.Closed += this.OnViewModelClosed;
                this.Window.DataContext = this.ViewModel;
            }
        }
    }

    public void ReplaceViewModel(TVM vm)
    {
        this.ViewModel = vm;
    }

    public event EventHandler Closed;

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        viewModel.Closed -= OnViewModelClosed;
        viewModel.Dispose();
        viewModel = null;

        Window.DataContext = null;
        Window.Closed -= OnWindowClosed;
        Window.Close();
        Window = null;
    }

    public virtual void Open()
    {
        Window.Show();
    }

    public virtual bool? OpenModal()
    {
        if (Window != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var dialogResult = Window.ShowDialog();
                var vm = ViewModel as BaseEditableViewModel;
                if (vm != null)
                {
                    dialogResult = vm.IsSaved;
                }
                return dialogResult;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return Window.Focus();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void Focus()
    {
        this.Window.Focus();
        this.Window.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    }

    protected void OnClosed()
    {
        if (Closed != null)
        {
            Closed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// If we Close the dialog via |X| button,
    ///     If it's and EditableVM && we did not save, we force to execute Cancel Command -> It'll call at OnViewModelClosed
    ///     Else, we fire Closed event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void OnWindowClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var editableVm = ViewModel as BaseEditableViewModel;
        if (editableVm != null && !editableVm.IsSaved)
        {
            editableVm.CancelCommand.Execute(null);
        }
        else
        {
            OnClosed();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// If we Close the dialog via ViewModel Commnd, we manually close the window && fire Closed event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected virtual void OnViewModelClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Window.Closed -= OnWindowClosed;
        Window.Close();
        OnClosed();
    }
}
```

BaseViewModel

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel : IBaseViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Fields

    private bool isBusy;

    private string title;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return isBusy; }
        set { SetProperty(ref isBusy, value); }
    }


    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { SetProperty(ref title, value); }
    }

    #endregion

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "", Action onChanged = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
            return false;

        backingStore = value;
        onChanged?.Invoke();
        this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed == null)
            return;

        changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of IDisposable

    /// <summary>
    /// The dispose.
    /// </summary>
    public abstract void Dispose();

    #endregion Implementation of IDisposable

    public event EventHandler Closed;

    protected virtual void OnClosed()
    {
        if (this.Closed != null)
        {
            this.Closed(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnClosed(bool saved)
    {
        if (this.Closed != null)
        {
            this.Closed(saved, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnClosed(object @return)
    {
        if (this.Closed != null)
        {
            this.Closed(@return, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

BaseEditableViewModel

```
public abstract class BaseEditableViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The save command.
    /// </summary>
    private ICommand saveCommand;

    /// <summary>
    /// The cancel command.
    /// </summary>
    private ICommand cancelCommand;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether is saved.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual bool IsSaved { get; protected set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the save.
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand SaveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return this.saveCommand ?? (this.saveCommand = new RelayCommand(async (x) => await this.SaveCommandExecute(), x => this.SaveCanExecute()));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the cancel.
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand CancelCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return this.cancelCommand ?? (this.cancelCommand = new RelayCommand(x => this.CancelCommandExecute(), x => this.CancelCanExecute()));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The save can execute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The <see cref="bool"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public virtual bool SaveCanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The save execute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The <see cref="Task"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public virtual async Task SaveCommandExecute()
    {
        this.IsSaved = true;
        this.OnClosed(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The cancel can execute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The <see cref="bool"/>.
    /// </returns>
    protected virtual bool CancelCanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The cancel execute.
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void CancelCommandExecute()
    {
        this.IsSaved = false;
        this.OnClosed(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The is state valid.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The <see cref="bool"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public virtual bool IsStateValid()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The save changes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The <see cref="Task"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public async Task SaveChanges()
    {
        await this.SaveCommandExecute();
    }
}
```

BaseWindow

```
public class BaseWindow : Window
{
    private readonly ICommand _closeWindow;

    public ICommand CloseWindow
    {
        get { return this._closeWindow; }
    }

    public BaseWindow()
        : this(-1)
    {
    }

    public BaseWindow(int pluginId)
    {
        this.ApplyCustomization();

        this.SetCulture();

        this._closeWindow = new RelayCommand(e => this.CloseWindowCmd(), c => true);

        this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
    }

    private void CloseWindowCmd()
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Applies customization to the base form
    /// </summary>
    private void ApplyCustomization()
    {


    }

    private void SetCulture()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Gran respuesta, muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo!